Torsional Moment using Pitching Moment Distribution
Hello aviation community!
I have a question regarding my calculation steps for determining the torsional moment and torsional angle deformation.
So the main goal is to find the torsion deformation distribution along the wing span using this formula:
$$\frac{d\phi}{dx} = \frac{M_T}{G \cdot I_T}$$
X is along wingspan direction. But in order for me to integrate this, I first need the torsion moment $M_T$. I therefore need its distribution along the wing, and is therefore again a function of x. This is the formula we have used:
$$M_T = \frac{1}{2}\cdot \rho \cdot u^2 \cdot C_m \cdot S \cdot l$$
From my understanding of this formula, the only thing that changes spanwise is the lever arm at between the lift and the aerodynamic center along the wing's cross-sectional area's plane $l$. Therefore, the torsion moment function becomes:
$$ M_T(x) = \frac{1}{2}\cdot \rho \cdot u^2 \cdot C_m \cdot S \cdot l(x)$$
This is where I believe my thinking process became wrong: I assumed that $l(x)$ is just the chord distribution along the wing span (we have an elliptical wing btw, so we're using this formula we found in one of Raymer's book):
$$l(x) = C(x) = \frac{4 \cdot S}{\pi \cdot b} \sqrt{1 - (\frac{2x}{b})^2}$$
I then plugged it into the $M_T(X)$ equation, which I then plugged back into Bredt's formula and get this:
$$\frac{d\phi}{dx} = \frac{\frac{1}{2}\cdot \rho \cdot u^2 \cdot C_m \cdot S \cdot \frac{4 \cdot S}{\pi \cdot b} \sqrt{1 - (\frac{2x}{b})^2}}{G \cdot I_T}$$
And so I tried to integrate this and you'd get this:
$$\frac{2C_{m} S^{2} u^{2} {\rho} \left(\frac{b \arcsin\left(\frac{2x}{b}\right)}{4} + \frac{x \sqrt{1 - \frac{4x^{2}}{b^{2}}}}{2}\right)}{\pi \cdot GI_{T} b} + C$$
But at this point, I do not know what C should be, and I also do not know if I am even doing this correctly. How do I find the torsion moment distribution $M_T(x)$ and the torsional deformation deformation $\phi(x)$?
It would be great to get some help on this.

"From my understanding of this formula, the only thing that changes spanwise is the lever arm at between the lift and the aerodynamic center along the wing's cross-sectional area". I think you wanted to say "the lever arm between the lift and the torsional center". Plus, you are speaking about lift but your equation is about aerodynamic moment

@sophit, Yes, you are correct that I meant to say the lever arm between the lift and the torsional center, but this changes along the wing span of an elliptical form, right? If so, I am not sure how to approach this...

Why should it change? Lift acts more or less at the quarter chord point and a wing is normally built so that its torsional center is at the same location so that the lever arm is basically zero. If the airfoil is symmetrical then also its pitching moment is zero.
